# Wordpress enqueue script after another

Tags: php, wordpress, royal-slider

I have an initialization script for a slider which must load after the slider's script is loaded, however, the slider script is being loaded by a plugin and persists at the end of the script calls regardless of me prioritizing my initialization script 999999 in the enqueue action. How do I get it to load after the plugin script?

In my child theme's `functions.php`:

```
function init_royalslider() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
       'sliderInit',
       get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/template-parts/royalslider-custom/js/sliderInit.js',
       array( 'jquery' ), '', true
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'init_royalslider', 9999999 );
```

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function init_royalslider() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'sliderInit',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/template-parts/royalslider-custom/js/sliderInit.js',
        array( 'jquery', 'royalslider' ), '', false
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'init_royalslider', 10 );
```

Pass `false` in the last parameter. If you pass `true` that means you saying to add the script in the footer as shown here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

**EDITED:** Replace `royalslider` with the plugin script name. As you are telling WordPress that your script depends on the `jQuery` similary you can add the another script name. In this way, WordPress add the script after the dependent script. Please refer [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) documentation for further details.

Comment: Thanks but I want the script to appear in the footer, after the plugin's script which currently persists as the last script called in the footer.

Comment: @pjldesign By which name the plugin is enqueuing the `script`?

Comment: @pjldesign Just add the name of the script in the dependency so your script will be loaded after loading the plugin script. You can do this like `array( 'jquery', 'royalslider' )`. Replace `royalslider` with the script name.

Comment: Ok but how do I do that if the plugin's script isn't enqueued or registered and therefore doesn't have a handle?

Comment: Got it. Discovered a function that adds handles to all scripts here: https://cameronjonesweb.com.au/blog/how-to-find-out-the-handle-for-enqueued-wordpress-scripts/